# Collapsible inlines in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there an up-to-date option for allowing collapsible inlines in the Django admin site?

I've looked at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/494, [How to add 'collapse' to a Django StackedInline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025597/how-to-add-collapse-to-a-django-stackedinline?rq=1) and Grappelli, but none of them seem to work for Django 1.6.1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, there isn't. You've shown two options; custom jQuery as well as Grappelli. What didn't work when you tried those approaches?

Comment: I added various jquery files and verified that I wasn't getting a 404 to them when visiting the page, but there was no change. I also installed Grappelli and found that not only was the UI (in my opinion) inferior, but also the existing collapsible fieldsets on the model did not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
clps = ('collapse', 'grp-closed')
```

or

```
css_classes=('collapse closed',)
```

These two ways seems to work for me with grappelli, You did not give code info to tell which is relevant,
POST your grappelli dashboard code(or anything else)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your inline model (django-grappelli==2.6.5+) :

```
fieldsets = (
    ('yoour_description', {
        'classes': ('grp-collapse', 'grp-closed'),
        'fields' : ('field1', 'field2', ...),
    }),
)
```